# distributing gcc together with program

Tags: license, distribution, gcc

Ok so i have a [project](https://github.com/Risa123/FPL) which requires [gcc](https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/) to work. I would like to distribute gcc binaries together with program for sake of convenience. What are legal requirements for this. Should i add copy of gcc license (GPLv3).
[Found answer](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#UnchangedJustBinary)

Comment: Have you read its license? What is not clear in particular?

Comment: If im required to for example distribute  the program together with gcc's license.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If your software does't require GCC to work (except for compiling source), you may distribute GCC with source or even binaries without licensing your app under GNU GPL, but you must send a source code and GNU GPL .

Your app won't be licensed under GNU GPL (if you don't want), because it's independent program, so placing it with GCC is aggregation, not derivative from GCC, so you don't have to do that. Even, compiling app with GCC doen't make your app GPL'ed

(answer just for clarify)

**THIS POST IS NOT A LEGAL ADVICE**